# Using awk, how to get desired output from multiple file sources

Tags: files, awk, merge

I have two files:

file1:

```
A,D
B,E
C,F
```

file2:

```
G,H,I
J,K,L
```

Using `awk`, I want to print:

```
A,D
B,E,I
C,F,L
```

How can I use `awk` to achieve this?

Comment: What is the relation between the 2 files? Is it a one one one comparison?

Comment: @Guru, I do not understand what you're asking. File2 looks exactly like the above.

Comment: @nowy1 : How will the output be if the file1 has 5 lines in it?

Comment: It's unclear from your sample how the files should be merged in the general case.

Comment: @Stephane Chazelas, See my edit. I changed the question and its description. You should now be clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll **assume** that extra field from the `n` lines of `file2` should be appended to the **last** `n` lines of `file1`:

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, 'FNR==NR {a[FNR]=$3; next} {print $0, a[FNR]}' <(tac file2) <(tac file1) | tac
```

```
paste -d, <(tac file1) <(cut -d, -f3- <(tac file2)) | tac
```

These solution add a trailing comma to the first line. You can remove it by piping the above through `sed 's/,$//'`

Comment: See my edit. The files have a different number of lines (file1 -> 3 lines; file2 -> 2 lines).